# Sum the values of a column

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, sum

I have the array:

```
array = [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "Price": 100,
                "Item": {"id": 1, Name: "A"},
                "Date": {"id": 1, Start: "202001"}
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "Price": 200,
                "Item": {"id": 1, Name: "A"},
                "Date": {"id": 2, Start: "202002"}
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "Price": 300,
                "Item": {"id": 3, Name: "B"},
                "Date": {"id": 2, Start: "202002"}
            }
    ]
```

And I want to be able to sum the values for a given period, as shown in the table:

| ITEM | 202002 | 202003 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| B |  | 300 | 300 |
| TOTAL | 100 | 500 | 600 |

Any suggestion? Thank!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Thank you! I will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this, it will start you down the right path

```
var aHolder = 0;
for(var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
   if(array[i].Date.Start === '202002') {
     aHolder = aHolder + array[i].Price;
   }
 }
console.log(aHolder);
```

Comment: Thanks! I think it can work. in the example you need to fix `arr` by `array`. It does the sum for a given `Item`, now I want to do the sum for a given `Date`

Comment: It works, but only with a certain period. I need to build a array with the results for each period. Suggestions

Comment: add another var , eg. var secondPeriod = 0, and also add another IF statement within the FOR loop